# Cohn's Measure Theory Page 64 - Differentiation under the Integral sign

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading Donald Cohn's Measure Theory textbook. I have attached the picture of Example 2.4.6. ("differentiation under the integral sign") which I seem to have trouble with:

[image: Example 2.4.6 of Cohn]

and here's the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem:
[image: LDCT]

---

I understood the entire example but **I do not understand how to prove that for each $t\in I$, $x\mapsto f_t (x,t)$ is $\mathscr A$ - measurable function** (this is required for using the Dominated Convergence Theorem). To see that for $t\ne t_0$, $x\mapsto \dfrac{f(x,t) - f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}$ is $\mathscr A$ measurable function, I did the following: Let $t\ne t_0$. then by hypothesis (a) in the Example 2.4.6, $x\mapsto f(x,t)$ and $x\mapsto f(x,t_0)$ are both integrable and hence measurable. Thus $x\mapsto \dfrac{f(x,t) - f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}$ is measurable. I cannot seem to justify why $x\mapsto f_t (x,t)$ for any $t\in I$ is measurable. Hints would be appreciated!

Comment: You are given that $x\mapsto f(x,t)$ is integrable which (for most people) implicitly suggests it is measurable

Comment: @FShrike You misread my question. I am trying to justify $x \mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (x,t_0)$ is measurable for any $t_0 \in I$.

Comment: Oh right. Well, the pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable. You don’t need to “suppose” $f$ is measurable on the DCT, because that is automatically true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_t(x,t)=\lim_n \frac {f(x,t+\frac 1 n)-f(x,t)} {1/n}$ and limit of  a sequence of measurable functions is measurable.

Comment: It's embarrassing that I forgot such a simple fact. :(